# mount tmpfs preserve current permissions

Tags: permissions, mount, tmpfs

I have a directory of a web application cache and this has the permissions 755 (default), and I configured setfacl additional permissions.

The problem is that when I restart the system, the information is always lost permissions.

As I can preserve them?

`/etc/fstab`:

```
none /home/rkmax/myapp/cache tmpfs defaults 0 0
```

`setfacl` command:

```
-R -m rkmax:rwx -m appuser:rwx /home/rkmax/myapp/cache
-dR -m rkmax:rwx -m appuser:rwx /home/rkmax/myapp/cache
```

Comment: you cannot preserve anything in that kind of fs, because is temporary filesystem, when you reboot or umount the fs, everything is lost

Answer (score 2):

find your user's UID

```
id -u username
```

find your user's GID

```
id -g username
```

in `/etc/fstab`

```
none /home/rkmax/myapp/cache tmpfs defaults,mode=0775,uid=998,gid=999 0 0
```

**resources**

- [Changing permissions in fstab in order to allow writing in Windows NTFS partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207180/changing-permissions-in-fstab-in-order-to-allow-writing-in-windows-ntfs-partitio)
- [Find a user's UID or GID in Unix](https://kb.iu.edu/d/adwf)

Answer (score 1):

You can put these setfacl commands in /etc/init.d/rc.local (if it uses the inittab style init setup) or equivalent in your system.

Comment: i think my system uses `systemd` because is Arch